# i want to make login credentials in generic way

Tags: java, android

if i do Hard coded i can login but i want to make it generic way,If credentials enter in Login screen,if it matches from Service it has to Login.I'm using in this way

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "Login Screen";

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=100000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextPassword;


String username;
String password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    editTextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emaiId);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

}

public void buttonLogin (View arg0)
{
     username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
      password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
    new TaskLogin().execute(username,password);
}

public class TaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\t Loading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("unsuccessful");
        try{
            url = new URL(URLConstants.getLoginURL());

            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));

            writer.write("{\"email\":\"jack@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"12345\"}");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();


            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.print("Result"+ response_code);
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            if(response_code==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line= reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                System.out.println("result "+result);
            }

            reader.close();
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginScreen.this.finish();
        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My URL consist of Username and password

```
{"email":"jack@gmail.com","password":"123"}
```

Comment: Hello and what's the question?

Comment: In above code i'm hard coding in BufferedWriter with email and password,That i want to make it in generic way. Please how to make it

Comment: so the question is `how to enter text into my app`, right? You can use some `EditText` s for that

Comment: my Login credentials should match with URL details.here i'm passing hard coded values which is in URL.I don't want to hard code i want to write a method for that to pass arguments generic way

Comment: do you know how to concatenate strings?: `"{\"email\":\"" + emailParam + "\",\"" + passwordParam + "\":\"12345\"}"`

Comment: no dude.. can you help me out from this..!! from many days i'm unable to solve this

Comment: Here is the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use JsonObject like below:

JSONObject job=new JSONObject();
        job.put("email",emailId);
        job.put("pwd",pwd);
writer.write(job.tostring());
```

where `emailId` & `pwd` are variable

Comment: its not working dude